# Which email detection regex is better?

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

Here I have 2 email validation regexps, which one is better and why?

```
new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]{2,}[.][a-zA-Z]{2,}$", "i");

new RegExp("^([a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})*$", "");
```

Comment: Related [Email validation using JavaScript](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/65190/91556)

Comment: Assuming this is for associating an email to a person, even if the regexp was perfect, that tells you almost nothing about the validity of that person's email. There is only really one way to check a person's email, and that's to email them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There probably is no 'good' regexp to validate an email id. The Internet Standard RFC has classified a 500-character long RegExp which according to them is the standard way to validate an email-id. Well, it does work, but it is so messy and almost impossible for most of us to understand.

```
(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])
```

If you have understood it, then, you need not read further. But if you haven't, go on.

[This page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) gives a decent info on how to validate an email id using regexp.

I use this one

```
RegExp("^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Z0-9.-]+\.){1,4}[A-Z]{2,4}$","i")
```

This works fine, atleast for me, but it fails to validate emails on .museum domain or any other domain longer than 4-characters.

Coming to your patterns, both of them are almost same except the fact that the first one uses `i` modifier and it allows 2 or more than 2 characters as TLD.
Hope it helps.

Comment: The other problem with the RFCs is that they only care about syntactically valid email addresses.  foobar@yahoo.con may be syntactically valid, but it's probably not what the user intended to type, even if the .con domain exists.

Comment: Your suggestion breaks on '@example.com and *@example.com  both of which are entirely valid.

Comment: IP addresses are valid server destinations, too.

Answer (score 6):

Both are totally broken as they both fail to accept the `+` character in the local part and one of them requires more than one digit for the domain name. Single-digit domain names are perfectly fine in some TLDs (such as `.de`).

If you really need more validation than a simple "has the `*@*.*` format" check, you need to read this answer on Stack Overflow: [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/a/201378/298479)